# Can Records in a single notification event ever have mixed event sources in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've configured an S3 bucket to invoke a Lambda on `s3:ObjectCreated:*`. This results in the Lambda receiving an event with the `Records`-property. Since the property is an array I assume this means it can, potentially, contain *multiple* Records where `eventSource` equals "s3".

But what if I were to set up a similar Lambda-invocation trigger in a different AWS service as well? Could the `Records`-array contain, for instance, one Record from S3, and another from the other service?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a mixture, but `Records` can have different structure. For example [Kinesis events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html) also have `Records`. [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) also use `Records`.

But if you compare Kinesis records with S3 event records, you will see they have **different** `eventSource`. For kinesis this is `aws:kinesis`, show for s3 it is `aws:s3`.

Thus, if you are worrying about this, you have to check for `eventSource`, or some other characteristics property of the `Record` for a respective service.

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely check `eventSource` for the expected source, but I'm wondering if I even have to?